# changing the direction of counter-clockwise arrows

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am using the following code to create arrows on a graph:

```
\tikzset{
    set arrow inside/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/arrow inside}{#1}},
    set arrow inside={end/.initial=>, opt/.initial=},
    /pgf/decoration/Mark/.style={
        mark/.expanded=at position #1 with
        {
            \noexpand\arrow[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/opt}]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/end}}
        }
    },
    arrow inside/.style 2 args={
        set arrow inside={#1},
        postaction={
            decorate,decoration={
                markings,Mark/.list={#2}
            }
        }
    },
}
```

It works. However, it is generating counter-clockwise arrows but I need clockwise arrows.
[image]

The complete code is as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[b]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,<->](0,10) node[above]{$u$}--(0,0)--(10,0) node[right]{$K$};
\node[below left] at (0,0);
\node[below] at (5,0){$K^*$};
\node[left] at (0,5){$u^*$};
\draw(0,5)--(9,5) node[right]{$\hat{K}=0$};
\draw(5,0)--(5,9) node[above]{$\hat{u}=0$};
\draw[-stealth] (3,2) -- (3,4);
\draw[-stealth] (3,2) -- (1,2);
\draw[-stealth] (7,8) -- (9,8);
\draw[-stealth] (7,8) -- (7,6);
\draw[-stealth] (1,6) -- (1,8);
\draw[-stealth] (1,6) -- (3,6);
\draw[-stealth] (9,4) -- (9,2);
\draw[-stealth] (9,4) -- (7,4);
\draw[blue](5,5) circle [radius=2]
[arrow inside={end=stealth,opt={red,scale=2}}{0.25,0.75}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}%
\figlabel{}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. Please, can you put a minimal working example starting from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Comment: Try changing it to `scale=-2`

Comment: Thanks. The `scale=-2` solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can reverse the direction of a lot of things in Tikz by setting the scale to be negative, here you had a scale of 2, which I've changed to -2, giving the result in the image above.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
    set arrow inside/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/arrow inside}{#1}},
    set arrow inside={end/.initial=>, opt/.initial=},
    /pgf/decoration/Mark/.style={
        mark/.expanded=at position #1 with
        {
            \noexpand\arrow[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/opt}]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/end}}
        }
    },
    arrow inside/.style 2 args={
        set arrow inside={#1},
        postaction={
            decorate,decoration={
                markings,Mark/.list={#2}
            }
        }
    },
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[thick,<->](0,10) node[above]{$u$}--(0,0)--(10,0) node[right]{$K$};
        \node[below left] at (0,0){};
        \node[below] at (5,0){$K^*$};
        \node[left] at (0,5){$u^*$};
        \draw(0,5)--(9,5) node[right]{$\hat{K}=0$};
        \draw(5,0)--(5,9) node[above]{$\hat{u}=0$};
        \draw[-stealth] (3,2) -- (3,4);
        \draw[-stealth] (3,2) -- (1,2);
        \draw[-stealth] (7,8) -- (9,8);
        \draw[-stealth] (7,8) -- (7,6);
        \draw[-stealth] (1,6) -- (1,8);
        \draw[-stealth] (1,6) -- (3,6);
        \draw[-stealth] (9,4) -- (9,2);
        \draw[-stealth] (9,4) -- (7,4);
        \draw[blue](5,5) circle [radius=2]
        [arrow inside={end=stealth,opt={red,scale=-2}}{0.25,0.75}]; % was scale=2 before
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```